# How can i use subscripts and units with fractional powers in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, subscripts, superscripts, fractions

I have the following simple document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\metre_{1}\tothe{1/2}}

\bigskip

% \si{\metre_{1}\tothe{-\frac{1}{2}}}

\bigskip

% \si{\per\metre_{1}\tothe{\frac{1}{2}}}

\bigskip

% \si{\per\raiseto{\frac{1}{2}}\metre_{1}}

\end{document}
```

Is there any reason why the three bottom lines failes to compile?
Is there any way to make it work?

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: `\tothe` is (roughly) `\textsuperscript`, so you have to wrap math contents in `$...$`.

Comment: I do not quite understand, this also fails in equations and so. Which part needs to be wrapped in math mode? Wrapping `\frac` in `$...$` makes the document compile but breaks the formating

Comment: The part in the argument of `\tothe`: `\si{\metre_{1}\tothe{$-\frac{1}{2}$}}`. How does it break formatting? For me the output looks like in your picture.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So using `\per` to obtain an negative exponent is impossible? If possible I would like to avoid hardcoding whether I use negative powers or `/`. Using your method I obtain https://i.imgur.com/6SK9IPq.png, which unfortunately does match the desired ouput. See the image in my post.

Comment: If you mean (simplified) `\metre\tothe{-1\per2}`, I think it is not supported (although it works, but doesn't produce the output you want). `siunitx`'s parsing mechanism doesn't get into the argument of `\tothe`, as it accepts anything inside it. For `siunitx` to understand that `\per\metre\tothe{1\per2}` is mathematically equal to `\metre\tothe{-1\per2}` it would require a _lot_ of parsing, and it would need a really large understanding of math, which is probably not in the scope of the package (yet). `\si{\metre_{1}\tothe{$-\frac{1}{2}$}}` matches your picture, though...

Comment: You can always define two units with the two styles and then switch easily between them...  I for example have `\DeclareSIUnit{\vsqrthz}{V/\ensuremath{\sqrt{\text{\hertz}}}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\vsqrthzp}{V\hertz\tothe{$-\frac{1}{2}$}}
`